# nvd3 multibar chart state incorrectly updating on legend toggle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

TL;DR: Try to figure out what state the radio buttons of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u9hqz6t7/) nvd3 multibarchart are in based on the console log - i.e. how can I reliably determine what data streams are currently being shown to the user?

Long version:

I'm trying to figure out which data streams/arrays are displaying in an nvd3 multibar chart so that I can update other DOM nodes with information relevant to those streams. The only trouble is that the `chart.state` seems to be returning the opposite of what it should: if I toggle a stream "off", `chart.state.disabled` is `true` for that stream ... except seemingly the first time something is toggled, when all `chart.state.disabled[i]` streams is set to `false`... the entire behaviour of that property seems like it isn't functioning as it should to me. Is it a bug or do I not understand how it's supposed to be used?

Some code to log the state of three streams, for example:

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on("legendClick", function() {
    var state = chart.state;
  console.log(state.disabled[0] + "," 
    + state.disabled[1] + ","
    + state.disabled[2]);
});
```

Comment: It's doing exactly the opposite of what it should be doing. That's rather weird . Open an issue on Github if this is coming from the latest version.

Comment: Yeah, it's coming from 1.8, but the trouble is it's not the **exact** opposite - something funny's going on in the very first toggle...

Comment: Issue opened https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1415

Answer (score 2):

Well, as is typical, I dig around for half an hour, can't get it working, post on SO and then go and try a different approach which immediately works:

```
chart.dispatch.on("stateChange", function(e){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.disabled);
}
```

So I believe it's a bug with the `ledgendClick` event that doesn't update the chart state correctly.